# What's wrong with Python datetime.now() in this piece of codes?

Tags: python, datetime

here is the codes:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> t=datetime.now()
>>> print(t)
```

And I got such a result:

```
2016-05-28 16:17:56.192505
```

How does the float number come? How could I solve it?

Environment: Python 3.5.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by `How could I solve it?` the given output is a string

Comment: Use [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 2):

The floating-point figure represents the seconds with microseconds. There is no need to "solve" it because it is working correctly. If you don't want to show it, format the date into a string with a custom format string that excludes the microseconds. For example:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2016-05-28 01:29:05'
```

Comment: It seems that I misunderstanded the function "datetime.now()". Thank you!